# Make exe file using pyintaller from a python script that takes arguments from command line

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets, pyinstaller

I wrote a python script that takes arguments from a command line (a path to a given directory in this case) and produce a GUI with files using wxpython. I have PyInstaller installed and I used the below command to produce an exe file, but when I ran it, i saw a window and in few seconds it disappeared and I was not able to enter the the arguments (path to a folder in this case).. Anyone know how I can do so that it can be able to take arguments and produce a GUI? I am using a windows 10 machine.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pyinstaller.exe --onefile "C:\Users\user165\Desktop\Device Tracing\get_last_update.py
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it work from the command line with `python get_last_update.py c:\Users\`?

Comment: Yes it works. @Igor

Comment: and if you run it with `get_last_update c:\Users`?